# C proxy server dropping requests

Tags: c, sockets, http, proxy, httprequest

I have a tiny C proxy server which I just want to get **one request at a time** from the client and send back the response from the server. **No pipelining**, no anything advanced, **just a persistent http connection**.

Structs:

```
typedef struct http_request {
   char* h_data;           // Header raw data
   int   h_size;           // Header size

   char  host[5000];       // Host to connect to
   char  resource[5000];   // Resource to get
} http_request;


typedef struct http_response {
   char* h_data;           // Header raw data
   int   h_size;           // Header size

   char* b_data;           // Body raw data
   int   b_size;           // Content-length of the body
} http_response;
```

Code:

```
while(1){

   // Waiting for user to connect
   int sock_user = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
   int sock_host=-1;

   // Accept 1 request at a time and respond
   while(1){

      http_request req;
      http_response resp;


      // 1. Client ==> Proxy     Server
      http_parse_request(sock_user, &req);     // uses recv(sock_user)


      // 2. Client     Proxy ==> Server
      if (sock_host < 0)
         sock_host=proxy_connect_host(req.host);
      write(sock_host, req.h_data, req.h_size);


      // 3. Client     Proxy <== Server
      http_parse_response(sock_host, &resp);   // uses send(sock_host)

      // 4. Client <== Proxy     Server
      write(sock_user, resp.h_data, resp.h_size);
      write(sock_user, resp.b_data, resp.b_size);
   }

}
```

Now this works good for a few first pages. Then the program blocks at step 1 and the browser just shows `Waiting for www.calcoolate.com...` all the time.

Firebug:
[image]

All of those *GET*, are requests sent to my proxy. I however receive only the first two of them. I double checked the return value of each `write()` and `recv()` and they seem to match exactly with what is expected. I checked for both -1s and 0s.

There must be something wrong with the logic of my proxy.. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use an existing proxy like [squid](http://squid-cache.org/) -perhaps with [ICAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Content_Adaptation_Protocol)- or an HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)? For which operating system are you coding? And a browser usually sends *several* requests on the same [HTTP connection](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html) and would perhaps have several connections. The [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is quite complex to implement reliably...

Comment: It is part of an assignment so I have to do it. Plus it's a good way to learn..

Comment: Oh and it's Linux. I understand that it's complex but my example is quite simple. It's meant to just handle GET requests and nothing more.

Comment: Then read a lot more about HTTP protocol.